# Capture previous value of the columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a table called Application which has information about applications.

```
 AppID      AppName     AppGroup     AppLocation     TeamSize    GrpSize 
  1         Nestle        Food           UK             6            12
  2         RedBull       Drink          USA            5            15 
  3          Ford        Vehicle         USA            9            25
```

Now when I update any rows in this Application table I want to capture the values to another table called AuditTable. Also I need to capture the previous values of TeamSize and GroupSize to that table too.

**For ex:** When I update the first row then the below Audit Table values should be populted as shown below.

**Audit Table:**

But Audit table doesn't have OldTeamSize and OldGroupSize columns.

```
AppID   AppName   AppGroup  AppLocation OldTeamSize NewTeamSize OldGrpSize NewGrpSize
  1      Nestle    Food       UK            6            3          12          8
```

I am trying to achive this in asp.net c#. Really appreciate any suggestions or thoughts.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried? What problems are you having? [ask]

Comment: Yea what tech are you using, some more details please

Comment: @Sayse - I'm trying to achieve this using asp.net c#. I need to capture the update action in the application table and insert the rows in the Audit table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways. You can insert into you AuditTable first before updating or use an update trigger.

Example 1: Insert then update

```
INSERT INTO dbo.AuditTable(Column1, Column2,...)
SELECT Column1, Column2, ... FROM dbo.Application WHERE (A filter you'll use when updating)

UPDATE dbo.Application
SET Column1 = NewColumn1Value,
    Column2 = NewColumn2Value
WHERE (Your filter)
```

Example 2: Trigger
//Google how to write the update trigger

Note: It always best to provide a code snippet of what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear which DBMS you are using, but I'd definitely consider triggers.
For MSSQL Server, you can create trigger, something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName
ON Table_Name
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
...
..
END
```

Inside the trigger body, use "inserted" dataset to get new values and "deleted" to get old values. For example, you can store OldGrpSize into variable using:

```
declare @OldGrpSize int = (select OldGrpSize from deleted)
```

Once you get old and new values, you just need one INSERT statement to store data into Log table.

Sure, you can use .NET and C#, but I believe it's much easier to do that with DB triggers. In this case, if you use triggers it's more safe, it's faster (less client-server communication) and it's easier for maintenance.